# WS2811 lights only turn red

Tags: arduino-uno

I've connected a strand of WS2811 to a 5V power supply and an Arduino Uno and no matter what I do the lights are always red. I'm using the fast led library and for some reason, the WS2811 lights are only red.

Comment: Please show us the sketch you're using and a schematic of the component connections.

Comment: difficult to guess ... you provided no useful information

Comment: My guess is that you have too many leds for the 5V supply you are using. Having to many leds on will drawing too much current. This will make the voltage droop. Since red leds will run at a lower voltage, while green and blue won't, only the red leds turn on. To solve this, you could try a smaller section of led strip, or set them to a very low brightness in code.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, turns out I had 12v WS2811's. Changing power supply fixed it for me!